# Visual Studio Config Transforms

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, transform, config

Suppose I have a Web.config like such:

```
<configuration>
    <elmah>
        ...
    </elmah>
</configuration>
```

Is it possible to remove the <elmah> node with config transforms? So far I've tried something like:

```
<configuration>
    <elmah xdt:Transfrom="RemoveAll"/>
</configuration>
```

Which doesn't work (according to Preview Transform). Althought this type of thing does seem to work on other nodes. Does anyone know how this can be removed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a **xdt:Locator** to get the match.

Try using the following:

**Debug:**

```
<configuration>
    <elmah name="debug" />       
</configuration>
```

**Release:**

```
 <configuration>
        <elmah name="debug" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />      
    </configuration>
```

Or without the need for name matching:

```
 <configuration>
            <elmah name="debug" xdt:Locator="XPath(//elmah)" xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />      
        </configuration>
```

or

```
 <configuration>
            <elmah name="debug" xdt:Locator="XPath(configuration/elmah)" xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />      
        </configuration>
```

As a note:

Currently the **Web.config** transforms are only applied during the Web Publish Pipleline (WPP) that is on Publish, not during debug, to enable them during debug check the following link: http://sedodream.com/2010/10/21/ASPNETWebProjectsWebdebugconfigWebreleaseconfig.aspx .

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed reply. Very useful thanks, especially your note at the bottom, which is another problem here. I was assuming that these transforms were applied, but they are not.

Comment: No problem. Yes, many developers are excepting the transforms to work while debug which isn't the case. That's why I've added a little note, hope it helps someone else too.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `xdt` syntax – it should be `xdt:Transform`, not `xdt:Transfrom`.